# How to create a bootable ISO from a full linux filesystem backup

Tags: linux, iso

I have a .tar.gz archive of the / folder of a linux server. How can I create a bootable iso from this, to launch an exact copy of the system in my local KVM setup?

I tried to extract the archive and create an image using genisoimage from the resulting folder

```
genisoimage -o output.iso dirname
```

But when I try to launch this image in KVM I get the following error:

```
Boot failed: Could not read from CDROM (code 0004)
```

Comment: Do you have to? It would probably be easier to create a block based disk ext3fs and boot that. Also, this isn't really on-topic here. I suggest you ask on the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have access to the original server: **Use clonezilla**

[clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) takes care of everything: all of the partitioning, the boot configuration, and can give you an image that reflects the space actually utilized.  It can also probably get the job done quicker than the time it took me to type this out, think about it, and and retrieve the links ..

There's a lot of variables.  One size does *not* fit all when it comes to filling in the gaps to make your current backup bootable with all the same configuration and options as the disk it was taken from. (i.e. BIOS and UEFI boot differently, there may also be partition or file references within a chainloader that are only valid for that point in time, etc.

**If you no longer have access to the linux server you took the .tar.gz backup from**:
then you'll need to install a bootloader - [GNU GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/), [Syslinux](https://syslinux.org) [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), etc.. There's also some GUI software that might make the job easier (or much harder).  I know Ubuntu has "Startup Disk Creator" which can create a bootable USB.  There's also cross platform tools like [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io).  If you have access to a windows machine, there's [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) which is IMHO across my limited experience probably the most flexible and robust GUI/Wizard style tool.

Comment: I actually have a grub folder in the /boot directory of the tar.gz file. Maybe there is something wrong with the partitioning when putting all of it into one ISO?

Comment: @TomAtix having files in `/boot` doesn't mean anything unless the MBR on the active partition is set to look for it.  Again - you need a bootloader.